# How can i apply texture to cylinders created using Ogre Procedural Geometry Library?

Tags: c++, ogre

I am using Procedural::CatmullRomSpline3 to create cylinders between 3 control points, now instead of solid cylinders i need to create dashed/ dotted cylinders so is there a direct way to do so or alternatively i have to make desired textures and add them to cylinders, how can i achieve this?